# Sencha Touch add update tree store data

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a tree store, and i would like to update its child node data.

My tree node looks like in this format

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "ContactName": "Aanitha Ps",
            "PhotoURL": "http://www.winreo.net/abraham/Images/avatar.svg",
            "items": [
                {
                    "Note": true,
                    "FollowUp": true,
                    "leaf": true,
                    "Email": "mak@gmail.com",

                }
            ]
        }
}
```

I can do updation in root node like this way

```
record=Ext.getStore('Contactsstore').getAt(0);
record.set('ContactName', 'John');
```

But not in child node..How can i update **Email** field in child node ? Please help me to solve this issue, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this

To update child node

```
Ext.getStore('Contactsstore').getAt(1).getChildAt(0).set('Email','contactemail');
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you will have to do it manually:

```
record.get('items')[0].Email = "New Email";
```

Comment: Thanks, tried 
record=Ext.getStore('Contactsstore').getAt(0);
record.get('items')[0].Email = "New Email";
but get an error message 
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined